# Obtaining Shear Sense indicators

Tags: qgis, symbology, geology

I have a geological map with faults and would like to display the shear sense indicators for each fault.

Where can I get the symbology and how can I display it correctly?

In GIS terms, I have a set of polylines and need to indicate for each of them a double-arrow (as shown below in the red circles). The symbol needs to be parallel to the line segment, one half-arrow on each side of the line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a line styling with three parts:

- One Simple line
- Two Marker lines each one: Two simple markers with different offsets and rotations

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]